# Lightbox or modal style effect for row in a table

Tags: css, html

I have a table (rendered using datatables.js) that shows some information.

When a user clicks on a button in the row, i open (which add a new tr) to the table.

I then show some fields in the new row including an confirm/cancel button.

What I'm trying to do is make it so that I can keep the user input on the row and disable everything with a given parent div, excluding the new row.

I can only think of using z-index, making the tr a high z-index and adding a new div to the parent position:absolute, at 0,0. Is that the correct way to go about it?  Is giving tr a high z index correct?

using HTML5/CSS3 (Jquery)

thanks

sam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done in so many ways. Here is one.

http://jsfiddle.net/Ktk9U/

Comment: thanks 3coins, used your example and made it so it works for other rows than the last one.  is it ok to set the z-index of a div in a td to be higher than other elements outside the the table? http://jsfiddle.net/vAL8K/8/

Comment: You might just want to have a new div and table having just the new row. You will also need an overlay which spans everything else but this div, increase the z-index of div so it comes over the overlay. Then once the data has been confirmed, you can destroy the new div with table and extract data from it into the original table.